# How to programmatically set TextBlock Foreground Hex Color

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have to use Foreground Hex color of a Textblock Pragmatically.it does not work.Please help me.

I have tried this example

```
txtHome.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
```

but I want use Hex color code not use Color.red etc..

Answer (score 12):

While there are answers that create unnecessary strings, I'd suggest just using the most efficient:

```
var brush=new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xD0, 0x20, 0x30));
```

I've just used the [`FromArgb`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.media.color.fromargb%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) method to convert the hex representation of a color directly. The first parameter is the alpha or opacity which you can always use 255/0xFF to specify full opacity. Then, it's just providing the 3 bytes representing the color, which are in the same order as they would have appeared in a common hex representation of a color. In the example above: `"D02030"`.

Also, you might consider creating a reusable resource representing the `SolidColorBrush` and adding it to the `app.xaml` file so it becomes globally available:

```
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="myBrush" Color="#D02030" />
```

Then, in code:

```
txtHome.Foreground =  App.Current.Resources["myBrush"] as SolidColorBrush;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
public class ColorConverter
    {
     public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(
                Color.FromArgb(
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
                )
            );
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it like:

```
txtHome.Foreground = ColorConverter.GetColorFromHexa(("#FFF0F0F0"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this function to convert hex color in to color value then u can set it on textblock.

public Color ConvertStringToColor(String hex)
        {

```
        hex = hex.Replace("#", "");

        byte a = 255;
        byte r = 255;
        byte g = 255;
        byte b = 255;

        int start = 0;

        //handle ARGB strings (8 characters long)
        if (hex.Length == 8)
        {
            a = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(0, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
            start = 2;
        }

        //convert RGB characters to bytes
        r = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        g = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 2, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
        b = byte.Parse(hex.Substring(start + 4, 2), System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);

        return Color.FromArgb(a, r, g, b);
    }
```

Color color1 = ConvertStringToColor("#F0A30A");
txtHome.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(color1);

Answer (score 1):

```
 txtHome.Foreground = GetColorFromHexa("#FF0000");

 SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
        {
            byte r = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16);
            byte g = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16);
            byte b = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16);
            SolidColorBrush soliColorBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, r, g, b));
            return soliColorBrush;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method mentioned below,

```
public SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
        {
            return new SolidColorBrush(
                Color.FromArgb(
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
                    Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
                )
            );
        }
```

and use it as

```
image.Background = GetColorFromHexa("#FF7b9a30");
```