# How can i change the background color of a stackpanel programmatically in windows phone app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I just want set the background property of **StackPanel** , currently i setting it by the following code,

```
statusPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Cyan);
```

But i just want to set a hexadecimal value. How can i do it??

Comment: This is a duplicate of (just a different color property): http://stackoverflow.com/a/22323969/95190

Answer (score 6):

```
statusPanel.Background =  new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0xFF, 0, 0));
```

If this answered your question, Please check right on left side.

Answer (score 1):

Use this function:

```
 public SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
       {
           byte R = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16);
           byte G = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16);
           byte B = Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16);
           SolidColorBrush scb = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, R, G, B));
           return scb;
       }
```

Usage:

```
statusPanel.Background = GetColorFromHexa("#RRGGBB");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ColorConverter.ConvertFromString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.ColorConverter.ConvertFromString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Method.

```
statusPanel.Background =
      new SolidColorBrush((Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("#FF010203"));
```

Comment: It's not available on Windows Phone.